# How can I find the limit of the following?

Tags: limits

What is the limit of this

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{2x+3}\right)^x$$

I know that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{2x}\right)^x$$ will give me $$e^2$$ but the I dont know what to do with the 3.

I have tried bringing them to a common denominator so I got
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{2x+7}{2x+3}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(e^{x\ln{(\frac{2x+7}{2x+3})}}\right)$$

And then Im stuck again

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about the natural logarithm function and its properties?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply determine the limit of the log.

Comment: You should show what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: I updated the post to show what I have done

Comment: Hint:
$$
\left(1+\frac{4}{2x+3}\right)^x
= \left(1+\frac{2}{x+\frac32}\right)^x
= \left(1+\frac{2}{x+\frac32}\right)^{x+\frac32} \left(1+\frac{2}{x+\frac32}\right)^{-\frac32}
$$

Comment: Hint: $f(x)^x = e^{x \,\cdot\, \ln f(x)}$

Comment: Or also $$\left(1+\frac{4}{2x+3}\right)^x=\left[\left(1+\frac{4}{2x+3}\right)^{\frac{2x+3}{4}}\right]^{\frac{4x}{2x+3}}$$

Comment: @SammyBlack I think that now you can add your answer again since the asker gave some context about its effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1 + \frac{4}{ 2x+3}$

And $g(x) = x $

Your limit is of the form $(1)^{\infty}$ , whose value is equal to $$e^{ \lim_{ x \to {\infty}}  {(f(x) - 1 )}{g(x)}} $$

Therefore , $$L = e^{ \lim_{ x \to {\infty}}  {(\frac{4x}{2x+3} )}} $$

Now $$\frac{4x}{2x+3} = {\frac{4x+6}{2x+3} } - \frac{6}{2x+3} = 2 - \frac{6}{2x+3}$$

Therefore , L becomes

$$ L =  e^{ \lim_{x \to \infty} { 2 - \frac{6}{2x+3}} } = e^2$$